# Change filename in file upload box

Tags: html, forms, upload

I have a file upload box and would like the ability to change the file name, but clicking in the box just brings up the Open Dialog. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Metro? HTML? WinForms? Mac? WPF? Swing? Silverlight? Win32? ASP.Net? SWT? MonoTouch? WP7? GWT? iPhone? AWT? Android? Blackberry? Pencil & Paper?

Comment: This would be a security issue if an arbitrary website could access files on your local machine. Therefore, file access is rather limited. What would be the reason at all to change it?

Comment: This is an internal website accessable by only a few.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of security thing that you can't manipulate the upload boxes. Browsers like chrome are entering there a `C:/fakepath/yourfile.jpg`string so nobody can spy files on your PC. You can't manipulate it with javascript as well.